# Start up script for Ubuntu dock in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock

Accidentally deleted script in start up applications in GNOME Tweak Tool in ubuntu 18.04 and now Ubuntu dock does not start at login. I get default GNOME dock only. Option to turn on Ubuntu dock in Tweak Tool extensions section is grayed out, but `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` is installed.

Can somebody tell what is the name of that script? (I'm almost sure it was a script. Really don't want to reinstall all default packages.)

Comment: Does you desktop environment look different from before? Could you [edit] your question and add a screenshot of your desktop environment?

Comment: The only script I have (and my system is pretty default) is the lid script. "ubuntu dock"  will only be open if extensions is turned on. Is it? (see the slider at the top of Ubuntu Tweak)